# Save php file in centsos

Tags: php, centos

I have created php file in centos
path sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

How to save this file and exit to command prompt.
Is there any save option or i can save it directly by cnrtl+s

Comment: The command for save in nano is usually `CNTL + O` (WriteOut), but it should show you this on the bottom two lines with the prompts. Either way, this isn't a question about programming.

Comment: You can try nanorc http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/nanorc.5.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use a text editor, and not about programming

Answer (score -1):

CNTL + O to save and CNTL + X to exit